# ng-disable all input elements

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Let's say I have 10 input elements on a page. I want to dynamically add `ng-disabled` to them based on the status of `ng-model`

For example:

```
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
```

I would not like to use a containing `<fieldset></fieldset>`.

Is this possible through something like a loop?

```
var allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
$scope.schoolClosed = true;

angular.forEach(allInputs, function(currentInput) {
  currentInput.setAttribute("ng-disabled", "schoolClosed");
});
```

Which would yield results such as:

```
<input type="text" ng-disabled="schoolClosed">
<input type="text" ng-disabled="schoolClosed">
```

Can I add angular attribute elements through the dom like this?

Comment: Why don't you write that in the original HTML?

Comment: can you use multiple ng-if ? like ng-if="schoolClosed"  or ng-if="!schoolClosed"

Comment: I have a lot, lets say 100 input elements. I just used 2 for the example. I would like to programmatically add `ng-disabled` to the form elements and not add that manually to them all. Is there a way without containing them inside a fieldset?

Comment: Could you possibly use ng-repeat to create all of your input elements? I would recommend this approach if you have 100 elements anyway, and then you would only need to write ng-disabled once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You can define a directive for the `input` element, which will get run for all inputs. Then you can have a service to store the disabled state, and "subscribe" to changes in your directive to set the disabled property directly without using `ng-disabled`.

I would imagine that you will need to make your service more complicated and maybe allow different named groups to toggle, rather than all or none. You could even specify the name of the group on a containing element or for each input.

You would also likely need to check in the directive whether it is a text input, so it doesn't get applied to every single radio button, checkbox, number input, etc in your application.

[Full Plunkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/gCqcg7weKCDiuhg1ZF7R)

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.service('InputDisableService', function() {
  this._isDisabled = false;
  this._subscribers = [];
  this.disabled = function(val) {
    if (arguments.length < 1) {
      return this._isDisabled;
    }
    var prev = !!this._isDisabled;
    if (prev !== !!val) {
      this._isDisabled = !!val;
      for (var i = 0, len = this._subscribers.length; i < len; i++) {
        this._subscribers[i].call(null, this._isDisabled, prev);
      }
    }
  };
  this.toggle = function() {
    this.disabled(!this.disabled());
  }
  this.subscribe = function(callback) {
    this._subscribers.push(callback);
    // invoke immediately with current value, too
    callback(this.disabled());
    var self = this;
    return {
      unsubscribe: function() {
        self.subscribers = self.subscribers.filter(function(sub) {
          return sub !== callback;
        });
      }
    };
  };
});

app.directive('input', function(InputDisableService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function($scope, $element) {
      var sub = InputDisableService.subscribe(function(disabled) {
        $element.prop('disabled', disabled);
      });
      var off = $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        sub.unsubscribe();
        off();
      });
    }
  }
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, InputDisableService) {
  $scope.inputs = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    $scope.inputs.push(i);
  }

  $scope.toggleDisabled = function() {
    InputDisableService.toggle();
  };

  $scope.isDisabled = function() {
    return InputDisableService.disabled();
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Inputs disabled: {{isDisabled()}} <a href="#" ng-click="toggleDisabled(); $event.preventDefault();">Toggle</a></p>

  <p ng-repeat="num in inputs">
    <label>Input {{num}}
      <input type="text">
      </label>
  </p>

</div>
```